# Editing form controls without document protection

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, forms

I have created a Word document (Word 2010, in format docx) with form elements (radio buttons, dropdown menus). Is there any way to set these controls active without locking the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you turn off 'Design Mode' in the Developer tab, your controls should be active.

This is both for testing, and allows you to send out fully-editable forms.

Comment: Great! Didn't notice that it was this easy :-)